# flextable::save_as_image() includes path to image when Rmarkdown knit to Word

Tags: r, flextable

When I knit an Rmarkdown to Word and include a table saved as an image using `flextable::save_as_image()`, the function seems to also paste the path to my image above the table.  How do I prevent the path from being included in the Word doc?
Here's a MWE:

````
---
title: "MWE"
output: word_document
---

```{r include=TRUE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(flextable, quietly = TRUE)
library(webshot, quietly = TRUE)
ft <- flextable( head( mtcars ) )
ft <- autofit(ft)
save_as_image(x = ft, path = "myimage.png")
knitr::include_graphics("myimage.png")
```
````

Here's the output I get:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`save_as_image` returns the filename that you saved the image to. You can hide it with `invisible()`.

```
invisible(save_as_image(x = ft, path = "myimage.png"))
```